# timeandmoney library with grails

Tags: grails, time, currency

Has anyone tried to use the time and money  [time and money](http://timeandmoney.sourceforge.net/) library with grails  , including persisting the money entity as a embedded object through gorm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK the library you mentioned has not yet been encapsulated into a Grails plugin. Regarding currencies, theres the [Currencies plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/currencies). I'm not sure if this suffices your needs, but it's worth looking at it. With respect to time and date, I recommend the [joda plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/joda-time).

Comment: Hi the currencies plugin uses float to store the amount .. which will lead to many error in common cases, you will find similar comments in other threads on this site itself