# Handle money value

Tags: grails, currency

I have to make a program in grails that have to handle money value, I would like to know if is better save in the db all the money in a unique value (ex: EUR) or if is better to save the money with the value that th user give me, and i would also like to know if exist API that convert money values.

Thank you very much anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [timeandmoney library with grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087701/timeandmoney-library-with-grails) which rightly suggests [joda money](http://www.joda.org/joda-money/) to do the job.

Much more knowledgeable folks [suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628637/best-data-type-for-currency) using your database' bigdecimal equivalent as the underlying storage type. This implies storing it all in a "base" currency and converting on the fly. For that, you can fetch currency exchange rates from the interweb. I've seen http://grails.org/plugin/exchange-rates but haven't tried it, yet.